# What is the cause of BRANCH SDK: Invalid "android-prefix" in <branch-config> in your config.xml error?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, branch.io

I have recently incorporated branch's branch-cordova-sdk into my application. Now when I use ionic package to build my .apk file, ionic package fails with the following error:

```
BRANCH SDK: Invalid "android-prefix" in <branch-config> in your config.xml.
```

My Config.xml file uses the required options according to the [docs](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking#configure-app) and is as follows:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.test.project" version="0.0.1">

    <plugin name="branch-cordova-sdk" spec="^2.5.17" />
    <branch-config>
        <branch-key value="key_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <uri-scheme value="testApp" />
        <link-domain value="com.test.project" />
    </branch-config>

</widget>
```

I have also tried adding the option android prefix with a dummy value like this: 
    
without any success.

It is not clear to me what is going wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

I am using the following:

- branch-cordova-sdk : 2.5.17
- @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
- CordovaCLI: 7.0.1
- Ionic CLI: 3.3.0
- @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
- @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.3.0
- @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
- Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0-dev ios 4.3.1
- Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please copy paste this single command in your terminal and see if it helps:

```shell
cordova plugin remove io.branch.sdk && \
cordova plugin remove branch-cordova-sdk && \
cordova platform remove android && \
cordova platform add android && \
cordova build android
```

[Source](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/issues/302#issuecomment-287087055)

Comment: May also want to update the Branch SDK version — it's 2.6.0 currently